# Rails: Warden/Devise - How to capture the url before login/failed access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to figure out how to redirect a user to the page they logged in from (or failed to login) using Warden/Devise. I figure there is a session variable somewhere that is either available or could be made available.

E.g.
Scenario 1:
Non-authorized user goes to protected page X;
Redirected to login page;
User logs in;
User redirected to protected page x

Scenario 2:
Non-authorized user wants to take a protected action on page x;
User clicks on login link;
User logs in;
User redirected to page x where the action is now available

Any pointers are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

There is a devise helper method called `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` (http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers) , and a session variable called `session[:"user.return_to"]` which stores the last url. The `after_sign_in_path_for` method needs to return a string, then devise automatically uses this path to redirect the user after login.

In my application controller I have put the following which redirects my users to the home page if the session variable is not set:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    (session[:"user.return_to"].nil?) ? "/" : session[:"user.return_to"].to_s
end
```

Comment: I had to use `session[:user_return_to]` as mentioned in this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5959018/337903

Comment: session[:user_return_to] works with this solution, as Nick said

Comment: A more concise version of this answer (using `user_return_to` instead of `user.return_to`): would be `session[:user_return_to] || root_path`

Comment: Easily done with 1 app_controller method and updating the after_sign_in_path in sessions_ctrlr http://stackoverflow.com/a/28507794/737275

Answer (score 1):

You can use `request.referer` to get the previous `URL`.

Answer (score 1):

If your using CanCan for authorization you can accomplish this be adding the following. If not, you should be able to adapt the concepts into your current authorization system.

app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:error] = exception.message
    if user_signed_in?
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      # Adds the protected page to the login url but only if the user is not logged in
      redirect_to login_path(:next => request.path)
    end
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    # if a protected page found, then override the devise after login path
    params[:user]["next"] || super
  end
```

app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb

```
  <% if params[:next] %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :next, :value => params[:next] %>
  <% end %>
```

Instead of using session variables this solution uses params in the URL to keep track of the protected page.

Comment: Any reason to not use the session? Is this valid with the latest devise version?

Comment: You might need to add something like this:   devise_scope :user do
    match '/login' => 'users/sessions#new', as: "login"
  end or else rails will complain that login_path is not found. That's with the lastest Devise as of Nov 25, 2012.

Answer (score 1):

*Wow, just realized that `devise (3.5.2)` does this all by itself behind the scenes (around `Devise::SessionsController#new` action), no additional controller modifications required.*

*If you need to explicitly `store`/`get` previous `location`, please see my previous answer:*

Currently (*Fall 2015*) there's a sexier way to do that:

`Devise::Controllers::StoreLocation#store_location_for`:

```
# Stores the provided location to redirect the user after signing in.
# Useful in combination with the `stored_location_for` helper.

store_location_for :user, dashboard_path
redirect_to user_omniauth_authorize_path :facebook
```

`Devise::Controllers::StoreLocation#stored_location_for`:

```
# Returns and delete (if it's navigational format) the url stored in the session for
# the given scope. Useful for giving redirect backs after sign up:

redirect_to stored_location_for(:user) || root_path
```

The methods handle related `session` key and value deletion after reading, all you need is to provide your `:resource` key (`:user` in the example above) and a path to store (`dashboard_path` in the example above). See [source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/store_location.rb) for the details.

As for the actual answer it'll be something like that:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied, with: :access_denied

  # ...

  private

  def access_denied(exception)
    store_location_for :user, request.path
    redirect_to user_signed_in? ? root_path : new_user_session_path, alert: exception.message
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    stored_location_for(:user) || root_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

here's the best I could come up with. Works perfectly also with facebook authentication. by adding more restrictions to the prepending of urls to the session variable you can remove more and more paths you don't want the user to return too (e.g. callbacks, splash pages, landing pages, etc)

```
#ApplicationsController

after_filter :store_location

def store_location
  session[:previous_urls] ||= []
  # store unique urls only
  session[:previous_urls].prepend request.fullpath if session[:previous_urls].first != request.fullpath && request.fullpath != "/user" && request.fullpath != "/user/login" && request.fullpath != "/" && request.fullpath != "/user/logout" && request.fullpath != "/user/join" && request.fullpath != "/user/auth/facebook/callback"
  # For Rails < 3.2
  # session[:previous_urls].unshift request.fullpath if session[:previous_urls].first != request.fullpath 
  session[:previous_urls].pop if session[:previous_urls].count > 3
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource) 
  @url = session[:previous_urls].reverse.first
  if @url != nil
    "http://www.google.com" + @url
  else
    root_path
  end
end
```