# Rails 3 - Devise redirects to form after sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, warden

In a blog app I want every user to access a form to post a comment.

When the user submit the comment form he is redirected to the Devise sign_in form if is not logged in.

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show, :new]
```

How could I once the user sign_in, redirect him to the comment form and fill all fields ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to take the user to comment form after every sign in, add in ApplicationController:

```
#after_sign_in_path_for is called by devise
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  comment_path...
end
```

If you want to take user back to the page they were at before sign in, you could save the current controller+action in session and redirect back:

```
session[:pre_login_controller] = params[:controller]
session[:pre_login_action] = params[:action]
```

And then :

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  if session[:pre_login_controller] && session[:pre_login_action]
    "#{session[:pre_login_controller]}/#{session[:pre_login_action]}"
  else
     some default path -- root url or comment path etc
  end
end
```

Comment: I've mixed your solution and Warden::Manager.before_failure and it works great !

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple solutions highlighted on Stack Overflow for redirecting to previous URL after a Devise login.

This is probably the most logical solution, and there is also a solution that includes CanCan (which I recommend using)

[Rails: Warden/Devise - How to capture the url before login/failed access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489064/rails-warden-devise-how-to-capture-the-url-before-login-failed-access)

As for the filling in forms, I think a simple solutions would be to restrict the comment box in the first place. Check if user is logged in (I think in Devise it's user_signed_in?) and if user_signed_in?  else "You must link_to sign in in order to comment". If you have the comments in an action such as #new, then you could restrict the entire new action through devise. For that, get rid of your :new in the authentification 'except'.