# How to make rails redirect without loading the template after sign_in with devise and cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, cancan

I'd like that after a user logs in, depending on it's role it redirects to some page, I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489064/rails-warden-devise-how-to-capture-the-url-before-login-failed-access), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704955/rails-3-devise-redirects-to-form-after-sign-in),  [and this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in) and yet I can't seem to do it right, I've tried each one and each has given me issues.

All I want is that after a user logs in, it redirects him/her to x_path, what I have technically works, but after it logs in, it tries to load the redirect_user template.

ApplicationController

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      before_filter :authenticate_user!
      protect_from_forgery

      rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |e|
        redirect_to new_user_session_path, alert: e.message
      end

  def redirect_user
    if current_user.role == 'Administrator'
      redirect_to rails_admin_path
    elsif current_user.role == 'C1' or 'D1' or 'M1' or 'M2'
      redirect_to upload_files_path
    end
  end 
end
```

Routes.rb

```
Siteconfigurationlistgenerator::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  match '/' => 'application#redirect_user'
```

Ability

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    #Define abilities for the passed in user here.
    user ||= User.new #guest user (not logged in)
    #a signed-in user can do everything
    if user.role == 'Administrator'
      #an admin can do everything
      can :manage, :all
      can :access, :rails_admin   # grant access to rails_admin
      can :dashboard              # grant access to the dashboard
    elsif user.role == '1' or 'M1' or 'D1' or 'M2'
      can :manage, [MaterialList, Inventory, UploadFiles, DownloadTemplate]
      cannot :access, :rails_admin
      cannot :dashboard
      can :access, [:upload_files, :download_template]
    end

  end
end
```

Currently, as I have it, it says something like template not found, it looks up the redirect_user template, in the views/application folder and it shouldn't, it should just redirect

Comment: User `root :to => "application#redirect_user"` instead of `match '/'...`.

Comment: I feel so stupid... I thought I tried that and didn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `routes.rb` should have:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions" }
```

You then need to create a `sessions_controller.rb`:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.role == 'Administrator'
      rails_admin_path
    elsif resource.role == 'C1' or 'D1' or 'M1' or 'M2'
      upload_files_path
    else
      super
    end
  end

end
```

You will notice that this method returns the path, it does not call `redirect_to` I have also added a call to `super` so that the default behaviour is called if none of the conditions match.