# Rails Devise - Pass URL to login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is there a way for me to pass an URL to the Devise login page, so that when a user logs in, he/she is redirected back to that URL?

Something like:

```
/login?passthru=/somethingawesome
```

Or is it better to set a session variable?

Answer (score 2):

Have a method to store the redirect location and a method to access the stored redirect location in `application_controller`:

```
def store_location(path)
  session[:return_to] = request.request_uri || path
end

def redirect_back_or_default(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  session[:return_to] = nil
end
```

Override the after_sign_in_path_for method to redirect the user to the desired location:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  redirect_back_or_default(resource_or_scope)
end
```

Devise Wiki: How To: [Redirect to a specific page on successful sign in out](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-out)

By the way, the above method is untested and you should test it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did

1) In your template set up your sign_in login
as follows: Im passing request.fullpath here as an example you can replace this with whatever you want.

```
<%= link_to "Log in", new_user_session_path(:passthru => request.fullpath %>
```

2) Next modify ApplicationController as follows: we add a before_filter which sets passthru in the session if it exists.  Then we override after_sign_in_path_for to look in the session for passthru.  If its not there it will default to root_path.  As long as you handle logins with params consistently everywhere this should work.  Although it might need some tweaking.

```
before_filter :store_location

def store_location
  session[:passthru] = params[:passthru] if params[:passthru]
end

def redirect_back_or_default(default)
  session[:passthru] || root_path
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  redirect_back_or_default(resource_or_scope)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Update for Newer Versions (Ruby 2.2.0, Rails 4.2.0, Devise 3.2.4):

**Application_Controller.rb**

```
  before_action :store_location

  private

  def store_location
    session[:requestUri] = params[:requestUri] if params[:requestUri].present?
  end
```

**Devise Sessions_Controller.rb**

```
  # Custom After Sign in Path
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_name)
    if session[:requestUri]
      session.delete(:requestUri)
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

**View xxxx.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to ('Get This'), some_require_auth_path(@something.id, requestUri: request.fullpath), class: 'button' %>
```